# how to add Yoast wordpress plugin to laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, browserify, yoast

I develop a website with Laravel and now I'd like to add Yoast plugin to it's blogger section to improve site blogs.
as I can see from Yoast github there is a [javascript version](https://github.com/Yoast/YoastSEO.js) of it that can be add to custom sites.
the usage help is not very helpful, so if any body can help me.

```
var SnippetPreview = require( "yoastseo" ).SnippetPreview;
var App = require( "yoastseo" ).App;

window.onload = function() {
var focusKeywordField = document.getElementById( "focusKeyword" );
var contentField = document.getElementById( "content" );

var snippetPreview = new SnippetPreview({
    targetElement: document.getElementById( "snippet" )
});

var app = new App({
    snippetPreview: snippetPreview,
    targets: {
        output: "output"
    },
    callbacks: {
        getData: function() {
            return {
                keyword: focusKeywordField.value,
                text: contentField.value
            };
        }
    }
});

app.refresh();

focusKeywordField.addEventListener( 'change', app.refresh.bind( app ) );
contentField.addEventListener( 'change', app.refresh.bind( app ) );
};
```

the usage help is with node.js but how can I add it to php backend and html+js front end.
thanks you.

Comment: I can not install yoast.js using npm.
I am using this command "npm install https://github.com/Yoast/YoastSEO.js#develop"

Comment: download it from git repo.

Comment: I have downloaded from git, now what to do? can you please guide me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After several days of searching finally find the answer.
to convert this or any kind of nodejs library to browser javascript supported just go to [browserify](http://browserify.org/) .
first install it by

```
  npm install -g browserify
```

then install all the library it needs with

```
   npm install <module_name>
```

at the end generate single js file with

```
   browserify <main.js> -o  <destination.js>
```

now you can add script to your html like

```
   <script src="destination.js"></script>
```

for YOAST library there is a browserify directory in example. I use browserify for the index.js file at root directory and add the generated file to this example html file and everything works like a charm.

Comment: I managed to generate the new bundled JS file from browserify, but I don't understand how to make the example HTML file work. Do you include the new .js file in addition to the other included file on the page? Also, the other included file is "example-browserified.js" which doesn't exist in the directory. Should that be changed to "example.js" instead?

Comment: you just need to add one generated js file to HTML, remove other files. the important note in HTML is the name and id of elements , all the work take place in js including text input change events.

Comment: I'm strulling with Browserify. I do this:

`browserify index.js -o ~/code/yoast/public/seo.js`
Error: module not found: "/home/eugene/code/yoast/node_modules/yoastseo/index.js" from file /home/eugene/code/yoast/node_modules/yoastseo/_fake.js

There is a Github issue from 2 months ago https://github.com/Yoast/YoastSEO.js/issues/1174 which says do `yarn install`.

I tried that and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: This solution does not work anymore. Is there anyone who has implemented yoastseo in laravel or any other custom code recently?

Comment: The solution is now available in Laravel using Vue js. Please follow the github https://github.com/gokulmhegde/Laravel-YoastSeo this is an assessment for SEO and Content analysis